# I'm trying to run a simple print script in Visual Studio Code with Python, but nothing shows up in terminal or output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've tried doing so much stuff, but nothing works.

My code and directory:

[image: my code and directory]

Terminal after I try running it:

[image: terminal after i try running it]

[image: another attempt]

I tried disabling some extensions. Nothing
I tried running the command in my terminal. Nothing.
I tried looking at other posts about it. Nothing.

Comment: Have you tried actually running the python program with `python3 hi.py` instead of just opening your terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not running your terminal in the same path where the file is located. The easiest way to go is to open the folder that contains your file using vscode. Right click on the folder and chose "Open with Code". Then your terminal will run there by default.

Otherwise change the directory to the correct location using something like`cd "OneDrive/documents/python stuff"`.

Or specify the path of the file you are trying to run. Something like this:`> python "/OneDrive/documents/python stuff/file_name.py"`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still doesn't show up in output. Works perfectly fine in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the script from VSCode UI, you should see the output in `OUTPUT` tab. In your screenshot you are checking in `TERMINAL`

[output tab check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13kNQ.png)

Nonetheless, as others have mentioned, you can execute it through the `TERMINAL` as well, typing `python hi.py`

Comment: Nothing shows in output. It's just blank.

Comment: Have you configured the [python interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter) in your VSCode? You need to have it in order to be able to execute from the IDE.

Comment: im completely new to visual studio code and python, and I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: The link I shared should help you to do it :). 
Nevertheless, I saw the image you shared in the other comment https://imgur.com/G5qwhK4. You are trying to execute the script in `C:/Users/Genne`, but the script is not there, as you shared in the screenshot of your post, it seems it is in `C:/Users/Genne/OneDrive/Documents/python stuff/hi.py`. Try to `cd` to the `python stuff` folder, once there executing `py -3 hi.py` should work.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it was trying to open the file there. How do I "cd to the python stuff folder"?

Comment: In the same terminal do `cd "C:/Users/Genne/OneDrive/Documents/python stuff/"` and then `py -3 hi.py`

Comment: Can you fix my output problem? It's on one of the other answers.

Comment: Can you share the output of `py -3 "C:/Users/Genne/OneDrive/Documents/python stuff/hi.py"`? I'd expect that the code is executed if you do so.

Comment: In the terminal, it shows the result fine, but nothing shows in the output tab.

Comment: @GameboyUltra alright, then we confirm your interpreter works fine :). For being able to execute it from VSCode you need to configure it there, for that you need to follow the [instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter) I shared earlier, with that you will be good to go. Hope it helps!